# Fixed Headers in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, css, jquery, header

I want to fix my header for my magento site. Please get me some solutions so that I will be helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add code in your header.phtml or footer.phtml

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if(height  > 150) {
        jQuery('#header').addClass('fixed-menu');
    }else{
        jQuery('#header').removeClass('fixed-menu');
    }
});

</script>
<style>
    .fixed-menu{ 
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9999999999;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can't praise you enough. This little gem saved me hours of development! Thank you.

Comment: @prashant Valanda nice one! but i am getting an error that jquery is not defined however there is already a script in jquery. Can you plz tell me why this is happening?

Comment: May be your jquery loaded after given script

Comment: @PrashantValanda, there is no id element with "header", how this will work?

Answer (score 1):

I personally would not install an extension for something this simple. Dig your hands in CSS file, and have a look there:

http://cssreset.com/creating-fixed-headers-with-css/

There is plenty of tutorials over the net to achieve what you are after. Also, do remember that you will probably need a bit of wiggling if you are using a custom theme.